# number of open files configuration not operational

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, limit

Addressing an error of `Too many open files` I was attempting to follow the [suggestions here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-too-many-open-files/)

Although `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.file-max = 70000
vm.swappiness = 10
```

and  `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
nginx       soft    nofile  10000
nginx       hard    nofile  30000
```

following changes to the sysctl command the errors are identical and

```
user@mo:~$ ulimit -Hn
4096
user@mo:~$ ulimit -Sn
1024
```

Ubuntu 14.04 environment.  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
[...]
events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}
[...]
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    development;
        root         /home/user/app/current/public;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location / {
            # proxy to upstream server
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
            proxy_redirect default;

            # track uploads in the 'proxied' zone
            # remember connections for 30s after they finished
            track_uploads proxied 30s;
        }

        location ^~ /progress {
            # report uploads tracked in the 'proxied' zone
            report_uploads proxied;
        }

  }
```

*update* as suggested `/etc/pam.d/common-session`
[...]

```
session required        pam_unix.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so

session required pam_limits.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete some more steps to increase max open files in ubuntu.

1. Edit /etc/pam.d/common-session and append below line

> session required pam_limits.so

2. Restart your system to apply the changes.

---

You can set limits to all users on system by adding below lines.

```
*       soft    nofile  10000
*       hard    nofile  30000
```

And reboot the system.

Comment: Tried that. ulimits are unchanged

Comment: @Jerome You have increased ulimit of "nginx" user, and I can see you are checking limit of "user" on console... Please send the output of ---- sudo -H -u nginx bash -c "ulimit -n"

Comment: sudo -H -u nginx bash -c "ulimit -n"    []  
sudo: unknown user: nginx    []  
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: @Jerome Please make sure user "nginx" present on your system, check user with the command -- id -u nginx ....... default user of nginx is "www-data" on ubuntu system, so you may have to set limit for the user which is running your nginx daemon

Comment: Instructive, as I'm not into digging into the OS. I had actually commented out that line in the nginx.conf file, not understanding the point. nginx is restarted. If I do `sudo -H -u www-data bash -c "ulimit -n"` I get the same # of processes (1024).  Should I conclude that `/etc/security/limits.conf` should be defining those limits for "www-data"?

Comment: @Jerome Yes, you have set limit for "www-data" too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18826/discussion-between-jerome-and-vaibhav-panmand).